# Trouble Downloading Excel File Updated with EPPlus: File Being Blocked - How to Resolve?

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, epplus

I am using EPPus-LGPL for Editing and downloading an excel.
But always I am getting the file as blocked; and i need to go to properties then Unblock the file to open always. I tried to Unblock using the code but it doesn't work.
So please give me the solution to unblock the Excel from code.

Button Click For Download Excel

```
 Protected Sub btnExcell_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExcell.Click
    Try
        Dim year As String = ""
        Dim month As String = ""

        Dim selectedYear As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(ddlYear.SelectedValue)
        Dim selectedMonth As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue)

        year = selectedYear
        month = selectedMonth


        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(year) Then
            year = ""
        End If

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(month) Then
            month = ""
        End If

        ' Parse year and month
        'Dim selectedYear As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(year)
        'Dim selectedMonth As Integer = DateTime.ParseExact(month, "MMMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month

        ' Calculate StartDate and EndDate
        Dim startDate As New DateTime(selectedYear, selectedMonth, 1)
        Dim endDate As DateTime = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1) ' Last day of the month

        Dim monthName As String = startDate.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

        Dim centralBankReport As New CentralBankReportVM()
        centralBankReport = PopulateCentralBankReport(startDate, endDate)

        ' Path to the original Excel file
        Dim originalFilePath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Files/CentralBankReport/sample.xlsx")
        Using package As New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(New FileInfo(originalFilePath))

            'Dim worksheet As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets("central_bank_of_somalia_Demo.xlsx") ' Replace "Sheet1" with the actual name of your worksheet



            Dim worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
            'Dim worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets("central_bank_of_somalia_Demo.xlsx")

            ' Modify individual cells
            worksheet.Cells("F20").Value = year
            worksheet.Cells("L20").Value = monthName

            worksheet.Cells("F55").Value = "$" & centralBankReport.TotalUSDToSO
            worksheet.Cells("I55").Value = "$" & centralBankReport.TotalUSDFrSO

           
            worksheet.Cells("F69").Value = "$0.00"
            worksheet.Cells("L69").Value = "$" & centralBankReport.OtherExpense
             

            worksheet.Cells("F75").Value = "$0.00"
            worksheet.Cells("L75").Value = "$0.00"


            worksheet.Cells("K43").Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")

            package.Save()

            UnblockFile(originalFilePath)
            ' Prepare the modified Excel file for download
            Dim fileBytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(originalFilePath)
            Dim fileName As String = "sample_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") & ".xlsx"

            ' Set the content type and headers
            Response.Clear()
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

            Response.Buffer = True
            '  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & fileName)
            ' Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes)
            Response.AddHeader(
        "content-disposition", String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "attachment; filename={0}", fileName))
            Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray())
            Response.End()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim message As String = ex.Message
        Response.Write("An error occurred while processing the request.")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Unblock Function Currently  have:

```
Private Sub UnblockFile(filePath As String)
    Try
        ' Use PowerShell to unblock the file
        Dim powerShellCommand As String = "Unblock-File -Path """ & filePath & """"
        Dim processInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("powershell.exe", "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command """ & powerShellCommand & """")
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True

        Using process As New Process()
            process.StartInfo = processInfo
            process.Start()
            process.WaitForExit()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Log or display the exception message for debugging
        Response.Write("An error occurred while unblocking the file: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the stream related to your original file doesn't closed at moment you are trying to open the file.

Thy move the `End Using` right after the `package.Save()` line.

And then replace the

```
Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray())
```

line by

```
Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(originalFilePath))
```